# Application.CUrrent.Mainwindow is null when i am running unit test

Tags: c#, wpf

`Application.CUrrent.Mainwindow` is null when I am running unit test in WPF. When I am running Unit tests I have

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMouseLeftButtonUp);
```

Here which in turn returns null exception in unit test

Answer (score 0):

This is expected; the `Application.Current` is set by the runtime and wouldn't exist in a unit test.

There are a few good options:

1. If this is UI related code; just don't unit test it. UI is usually tested via a coded UI test or other end-to-end test.
2. Create a service that wraps `Application.Current` so that you can mock it in your unit test.
3. Do a null check before registering the event handler.